# Inconsistant results: "select * from sysobjects where ID = object_ID(N'TableName') and OBJECTPROPERTY(ID, N'IsUserTable') = 1"

Tags: sql-server-2012

I scripted our development database locally. The Stored procedures in our app has code all over the place that checks to see if a table exists and if so, drops the table and recreates it. I noticed that when I run the code in my local database that the check to see if the table exists does not work the same as when running in development. In particular, I noticed that the OBJECTPROPERTY(ID, N'IsUserTable') returns NULL when running locally but returns 1 in DEV.

```
if exists (select * from [CLASS].DBO.sysobjects where ID = object_ID(N'[CLASS].DBO.[CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(ID, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'EXISTS!'
    drop table [CLASS].DBO.[CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT]
END
    ELSE PRINT 'NO!'
GO

CREATE TABLE [CLASS].DBO.[CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT] (
    [CLIENT_ID] [bigint] NULL ,
    [CLIENT_Name] [char] (70) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [GOC] [char] (3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [AC_DATE] [datetime] NULL ,
    [EFF_Date] [datetime] NULL ,
    [AC_STATUS] [char] (8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [REPORTING_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [V2V_IND] [char] (1) NULL,  --2017.10
    [LAST_OPER_ID] [char] (8) NULL,
    [LAST_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

---

```
NO!
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT' in the database.
.
```

I know that if I change the check as follows

```
if exists (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT]') AND type in (N'U'))
drop table [CLASS].DBO.[CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT]
```

that it will work, but I do not want to change many occurences of this code just to run the app on my local database.

```
SELECT @@version --on dev server
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU7) (KB3205051) - 11.0.6579.0 (X64) 
    Dec 22 2016 11:18:09 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

SELECT @@version --on local workstation
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3156.0 (X64) 
    May  4 2015 18:48:09 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

When I script the tables in each table, they appear to be same same.  What could explain the difference?

Comment: Have you considered this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is that `OBJECTPROPERTY` is scoped to the current database. Rather than use that you could use the object_type option in your `OBJECT_ID` call (so `OBJECT_ID(N'Database.Schema.ObjectName', 'U')` where U represents a user table (you can check the relevant object_type value from the `type` column in [sys.objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql)).

You can also simplify your query by just checking for the existence of the object_id, so no need to query again sys.objects in that database.

This would make your query look like the following:

```
IF (SELECT object_ID(N'[CLASS].DBO.[CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT]', 'U')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'EXISTS!'
    drop table [CLASS].DBO.[CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT]
END
    ELSE PRINT 'NO!'
GO

CREATE TABLE [CLASS].DBO.[CDB_SCRB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT] (
    [CLIENT_ID] [bigint] NULL ,
    [CLIENT_Name] [char] (70) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [GOC] [char] (3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [AC_DATE] [datetime] NULL ,
    [EFF_Date] [datetime] NULL ,
    [AC_STATUS] [char] (8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [REPORTING_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [V2V_IND] [char] (1) NULL,  --2017.10
    [LAST_OPER_ID] [char] (8) NULL,
    [LAST_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```